# Sequence in codes inside a function - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a function which will be triggered when a like button is clicked, something like the facebook "like" buttons. I have the first part, and the second part as commented below. The problem is that, when the code runs, there is no sequence in the codes. For example I need the first part to run and then the second part, but sometimes the second part runs first. How can I add a sequence as priority to run?

```
 @IBAction func likeBtn(sender: AnyObject) {


         /* first part */        

        if likeTitle == "Like" {

       var likeObj = PFObject(className: "likes")

        likeObj["userName"] = PFUser.currentUser()!.username
        likeObj["tweetObjectId"] = objectid.text

        likeObj.save()

        likeBtn.setTitle("Liked", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        }


        /* second part */



            var likeCount = PFQuery(className: "likes")
            likeCount.whereKey("ObjectId", equalTo: objectid.text!)
            var likedUsersCount = likeCount.countObjects()

            var addLikeCountQuery = PFQuery(className: "comments")
            addLikeCountQuery.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: objectid.text!)

            addLikeCountQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {

                (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                for object in objects! {

                    var ob:PFObject = object as! PFObject

                    ob["numberOfLikes"] = likedUsersCount

                    ob.save()
                }

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first part will only run if `likeTitle == "Like"`, so if `likeTitle != "Like"` then your first part won't run, but the second part will always run.

Another problem could (keyword here is "could" :-)) be that in your first part, you call `likeObj.save()`. I don't know what your code looks like, but this could be asynchronous, meaning that it'll save whatever needs to be saved in a background thread to not block the main thread, and meanwhile your second part code will continue running on the main thread.

If that's the case, then maybe you should consider some sort of callback to be executed when the save operation is completed, and in that callback, you invoke your second part.

Comment: Even if likeTitle==like sonetimes the second part runs. I gues it might be, before the first part finishes saving to database, the second part becomes already run sometimes. How can i fix this with a callback method?

Comment: You could add a parameter to your `save()` method which is a function. In your `save()` method you need to know when the saving is actually done. And when it is, you call the function that you provided as a parameter to your function.

Comment: Hello Pdodsk, how can i create an input that the system will know that the saving action is completed?

Comment: I see now that you are using Parse. If you look at the documentation for [PFObject](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#/), you'll see that the `save()` method runs synchronously, so in theory it should block the main thread while it saves. To determine whats causing this behaviour, you could try to comment out the line with `likedObj.save()` and see if that makes your code run as expected. If it does, then there's your problem :-). If you look at the documentation for PFObject, you'll see that there is a `saveInBackgroundWithBlock`, maybe that could be of used instead then?